# use shell curl to post whith a checkbox array

Tags: arrays, shell, curl, checkbox

The http code like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkbox[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="checkbox[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="checkbox[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="checkbox[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="5" name="checkbox[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="6" name="checkbox[]">
```

It will be checked some value more than one
I see that, checkbox like this is for php and have to be serialized and I want to use curl on unix shell to do this,what can i do?

Comment: You want to use curl from the shell or php?

Comment: Using `curl -X post --data "?checkbox[]=2&checkbox[]=4"` doesn't work?