# Submit form with PHP cURL, multiple checkboxes with same name

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to submit an external form using PHP cURL. All form fields are working fine, except a problem I have with multiple checkboxes with the same name.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="same_name" value="value_1">
<input type="checkbox" name="same_name" value="value_2">
<input type="checkbox" name="same_name" value="value_3">
```

I have no problem with passing ONE of the checkboxes in the cURL request. In my POST string, I just do:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '...&same_name=value_1');
```

But now, I want to submit the form with multiple boxes checked. I tried the suggestion in the comments on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541062/use-shell-curl-to-post-whith-a-checkbox-array) StackOverflow post:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '...&same_name[]=value_1&same_name[]=value_2');
```

But then I get a response which is based on no checked checkboxes at all, ergo it doesn't work.

Basically, how can I submit such an array correctly in this request? Who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, it's really weird. I just tried to setup my own page (this one is external) with the following code, and it indeed seemed impossible to select more than one value:

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="checkbox" name="same_name" value="1">Value 1<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="same_name" value="2">Value 2<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="same_name" value="3">Value 3<br />
 <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
 print_r($_POST);
}
?>
```

But after some tweaking, I think I got it working anyhow with ..&same_name=value_1&same_name=value_2.

I don't know HOW they do it on their serverside, but it appears to work!

Comment: It's bacause you're doing it with PHP. PHP needs that array-like format `param[]=value`. But there are some other web servers that accept `p=1&p=2` (AFAIR i.e. java ones). You can try to look at response headers to find out.

Answer (score 2):

If it's your form (you can change the code), change checkbox's name to `same_name[]`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="same_name[]" value="value_1">
<input type="checkbox" name="same_name[]" value="value_2">
<input type="checkbox" name="same_name[]" value="value_3">
```

and call `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '...&same_name[]=value_1&same_name[]=value_2');`, it's OK.

If it's external - you can't have multiple choice.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot change it as it is external.

But it seems like the form IS accepting multiple choices in the browser itself anyway, regardless that the name doesn't have an [] at the end. It's basically a form that allows you to select which data should be available in a table that is generated after submitting, and if you select multiple checkboxes, they all appear (so 100% sure it allows multiple choice) - but only when tried in the browser, not with my cURL request.

Comment: Can you show that page? There could be some js code that does the job.

Comment: It's behind a login. Let me dive into devtools, tho if I look at the post request into Chrome Dev Tools, this is the request that is sent: &same_name=value_1&same_name=value_2. That appears to work in the browser. But probably cURL filters that out somehow, as it thinks it's not possible to have the same variable twice in a request...

Answer (score 0):

It is totally fine to pass an array for multi-value fields. It is usually a  checkbox, but it can be any field such as multi-select. 
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is capable to handle this correctly and in the backend you get it as an array - identical to the submission from

```
<input type="checkbox" name="same_name" value="1">Value 1
<input type="checkbox" name="same_name" value="2">Value 2
<input type="checkbox" name="same_name" value="3">Value 3


$fields['name']='Smith';
$fields['email']='you@your-domain.com';
....
$fields['same_name'][]=1;
$fields['same_name'][]=2;
$fields['same_name'][]=3;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```